# looking for small associated array where key is automatic generated and has linear memory consumption

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, collections

Like the title says, I am looking for an associated array (like a map) with linear memory consumption (like a std::vector) where the keys are automatic generated for new entries. N < 128.

For example we would use this for an observer pattern, were you can register callbacks to a value change event. In return, you get an id (integer). With this id you can later unregister your callback.

Pseude code:

```cpp
/// Registers a callback and returns an associated id to it.
int register_callback(std::function callback);

/// Returns true if callback was unregistered for given id.
bool unregister_callback(int id);
```

Since this should be used inside embedded devices with memory restriction, I wouldn't use a map as container (see here: http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2016/06/14/how-much-memory-does-an-stl-container-use/, map uses ~5 times more memory than a vector).

I have some ideas how to implement this myself, but I wonder if there exists any name/concept for this already?

This would be my idea:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class custom_map { // Totally unsure with naming
    // coll_ is sorted.
    std::vector<std::pair<uint8_t, T>> coll_;
public:
  uint8_t add(T) {
    // Find unused id by iterating over coll_,
    // If ((prev id + 1) != (next id)), free id found. 
    // Insert into coll new pair and sort.
  }

  bool remove(uint8_t id) {
    // Remove element in coll with associated id 
    // Binary search would be faster but only for bigger sizes, so linear search?
  }

  // Iterator concept begin/end... to iterate over collection.
};
```

Comment: I think the term you want is "associative array."

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to hold seperate id in your object. You can use index of vector as id. That would be much faster.

```
template<typename T>
class custom_map { // Totally unsure with naming

std::vector<T*> coll_;
public:
uint8_t add(T*obj) {
    // Find unused id by iterating over coll_,
    for (int i = 0; i < coll_.size(); ++i) {
        if (coll_[i] == nullptr) {
            coll_[i] = obj;
            return i;
        }
    }
    coll_.push_back(obj);
    return coll_.size() - 1;
}

bool remove(uint8_t id) {
    coll_[id] = nullptr;
}

 // Iterator concept begin/end... to iterate over collection.
};
```

Comment: Does not work. If anyone other removes a callback, index and iterators are not valid anymore.

Comment: @Viatorus Yes it will. I dont know what is other requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You're possibly over complicating the problem, you can simply use the index into the vector as your key:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class custom_map {
  std::vector<T> coll_;
public:
  size_t add(const T& t) {
    for (auto it = coll_.begin(); it != coll_.end(); ++it)
    {
      if (!(*it))
      {
        *it = t;
        return it - coll_.begin();
      }
    }
    coll_.push_back(t);
    return coll_.size() - 1;
  }

  bool remove(size_t id) {
    if (id >= coll_.size() || !coll_[id]) {
      return false;
    }
    coll_[id] = {};
    // remove empty elements from the end of the list
    if (id == coll_.size()-1) {
      auto toRemove = std::count_if(coll_.rbegin(), coll_.rend(), [](const T& t) { return !t; });
      coll_.resize(coll_.size() - toRemove);
    }
    return true;
  }
};

int main()
{
  custom_map<std::function<void()>> map;
  auto i = map.add([](){std::cout << "1\n"; });
  map.remove(i);
}
```

This will only work with types that are default initialised to a value convertible to false (like `std::function`), for other types you can just wrap the type in `std::optional`, for example (the map will actually work with `int` too but `0` being an empty value might not be what you want):

```
int main()
{
  custom_map<std::optional<int>> map;
  auto i = map.add(10);
  map.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: Does not work. If anyone other removes a callback, index and iterators are not valid anymore

Comment: @Viatorus why? it only sets the unused element to null, it doesn't resize the vector unless the element is at the end of the vector, indexes after the removed element remain valid